# When, exactly, do floated divs move down?

Tags: html, css

To clarify, this exact same thing happens by default with bootstrap "column" divs (when used properly with the container/row classes). HOWEVER, I am NOT using bootstrap, or asking about bootstrap.

Let's say I have three divs, all floated left. At some point, on window resize, the rightmost div moves below the leftmost div, as if "clear:both" was used.

I have read countless articles such as http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and all about the parent horizontal collapse. I also looked through the answers here. I am not seeing the answer (or even the question) anywhere. Example (make display port extremely wide-screen to see problem):

http://jsfiddle.net/bwzm5m5h/2/

It doesn't help, but I am including it to show I have tried. Would really appreciate a general-rule on what, exactly, triggers the div to pull down.

edit: Stackoverflow forces me to include some code, ignore it:

```
code
```

Comment: There is a reason that "_Stackoverflow forces me to include some code_." For best results, consider exploring the reason.

Comment: `div` elements are block level elements so think of them as bricks. If the two bricks exceed the width of their container, when floating, the one that would exceed is pushed under its sibling.

Comment: What's wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: You want to make the three `<div>` to be re-sized when the window is re-sized so that the third `<div>` don't placed at the bottom of the first `<div>`? I noticed it in the fiddle.
I'll post the answer if you want it.

Comment: Did you add `edit: ...` on your first draft, without actually editing your post?

Comment: Tyblitz gave the answer I needed, thank you for the offers to help guys. 

George, posting all my code here would be excessive and distracting. Pieces would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a secret: if you pay close attention the the viewport, you will see that your elements start to expand to the bottom and a scrollbar appears. And the `vw` unit measures the width of the viewport, so it is not responsive to the lay-out change the scrollbar brings.

 Set `body { overflow:hidden }` to check it out.

Quickest solution: wrap your `.dataBox`'es in a container, give the container 100% width, and the databoxes 33%

According to [this article](http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/), the issue should only be present on Windows and not on Mac, due to how the browsers render the scrollbars on the respective platforms.
Note: `vw` units are not compatible with IE8-, Android 4.1, 4.3 & Opera Mini 8; and IE9 only supports vw, not vmin and vmax. More info at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw).

Comment: That did it, thank you very much. I have seen the recommendation to wrap it like that before, but I never understood why I would do that, as opposed to using vw. It never even occurred to me that the scroll-bar affected the number. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually I didn't know/ look it up; it was just a logical reasoning. But [this article](http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) confirms, and apparently Mac browser scrollbars are 'smart', whereas Windows ones aren't... And also be aware that vw units are not compatible with IE8- & IE9 doesn't support vmin/vmax. And for the ones who have an old Nokia phone (like me), Opera Mini (latest) doesn't support them either :p